# get TensorFlow tf.Operation inputs by name

Tags: tensorflow

Let `op` be a `tf.Operation`. I can get its inputs via `op.inputs`. But the inputs also have names defined by the op type, which I probably can extract somehow via `op.op_def`. But is there an easy way?

In the end, I would want a dict like `{input_name[i]: op.inputs[i] for i ...}`.

My current solution:

```
def get_protobuf_fields(obj):
  """
  :param obj: protobuf object
  :rtype: dict[str]
  """
  return {k.name: v for (k, v) in obj.ListFields()}


def get_operation_input_names(op):
  """
  :param tf.Operation op:
  :rtype: list[str]
  """
  op_def_fields = get_protobuf_fields(op.op_def)
  args_pb = [get_protobuf_fields(a) for a in op_def_fields["input_arg"]]
  return [a["name"] for a in args_pb]
```

Then you get the dict like:

```
inputs_by_name = dict(zip(get_operation_input_names(op), op.inputs))
```

For example, for `op = tf.add(3,4).op`, you would get `inputs_by_name = {'x': ..., 'y': ...}`.

Is there a simpler way?